# How to keep the main page as "index.php" while still Requiring log-in on other pages - yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm running into some difficulty in using the added componenet requirelogin.php . This is the component that I've added

```
    <?php
class RequireLogin extends CBehavior
{

    public function attach($owner)
    {
        $owner->attachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this, 'handleBeginRequest'));
    }


    public function handleBeginRequest($event)
    {

        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && !in_array($_GET['r'],array('site/login', 'site/index'))) {
        Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note how 'site/index' is allowed in this as a page that I can visit.

Now, in my main.php I added the following

```
'behaviors' => array(
    'onBeginRequest' => array(
        'class' => 'application.components.RequireLogin'
    )
),
```

Now, these two force me to go to site/login everytime - even though I have done as other stackoverflow answers have told me to and added

```
// sets the default controller action as the index page 
        'defaultController' => 'site/index',
```

Could anyone explain why this hasn't made my start page site/index?

**_____________** ADDITION

I've also figured out that when I am going to the base action (i.e. mywebsite.com)  it is NOT going to site/index. rather it is directly redirecting to site/login. This, however, does not occur, when I comment out the behaviors .

Comment: Did you try to log the value of $_GET['r'] in your handler to see if this is the reason the user is redirected?

Comment: So, when I tried to print out $_GET['r] in component require log-in nothing printed out!

Comment: So this is the reason why your if condition doesn't work! And your get parameter is empty even with an url like index.php?r=site/index ?

Comment: I remove my post but you can try to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] instead of $_GET['r'].

Answer (score 0):

So, thank you darkheir for all of your work on this. 
Ultimately, what happened was the $_GET['r] in the *base path* was simply '' because r was not point to anything in particular. As a result, when ever I looked in_array($_GET['r']) what I was getting in the very bae path was in_array('', array('site/login', 'site/account')) Now, unfortunately, '' is neither site/login or site/account so the page redirected using

```
Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
```

The fix to this problem was

```
   public function handleBeginRequest($event)
{
    // note that '' is now one of the options in the array 
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && !in_array($_GET['r'],array('site/login', 'site/index', '' ))) {
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
    }
}
```